# How to change font size of segmented control and prevent it from changing back to default size after changing segment

Tags: objective-c, ios, uisegmentedcontrol, font-size

I am using the following code to implement and subsequently change the font size of each segment in the UISegmented Control

```
//Set up segment control
UISegmentedControl *tempSegmentControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc]initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Friends",@"Popular", nil]];
tempSegmentControl.frame = CGRectMake(-8, -1, 336, 30);

self.segmentControl = tempSegmentControl;
[self.segmentControl setWidth:168 forSegmentAtIndex:0];
[self.segmentControl setWidth:168 forSegmentAtIndex:1];
self.segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;
[self.segmentControl addTarget:self action:@selector(toggleControls:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[self.segmentControl setSegmentedControlStyle:UISegmentedControlStylePlain];

//TO CHANGE FONT SIZE OF EACH SEGMENT
for (id segment in [self.segmentControl subviews]) 
{
    for (id label in [segment subviews]) 
    {
        if ([label isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
        {
            [label setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
            [label setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14]];
        }
    }           
}
```

This works initially (see screenshot below)

[image]

However, after I click on the "popular" tab (inactive tab), the font size seem to return to their original default font size

[image]

What can I do to prevent the font size from changing back to the default size?

Comment: Can't you set the initial font in Interface Builder?

Answer (score 9):

Probably not the cleanest way, but it works if you run the for-loop on the 'value Changed' event of the UISegmentedControl control.

**Update:**
This is the proper way, available in iOS 5 and later:

```
NSDictionary *textAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14], UITextAttributeFont, nil];
[self.segmentControl setTitleTextAttributes:textAttributes forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: UITextAttributeFont is deprecated on iOS7 later. Use NSFontAttributeName instead.

Answer (score 1):

http://chris-software.com/index.php/tag/uisegmentedcontrol/

check out this its ans

```
codeButton.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
codeButton.momentary = YES;
```